# How to sort each row by words using excel?

Tags: excel, sorting, row

I have a excel file looking like this

```
     A         B         C
1| A_xxxx | B_xxxx  | C_xxxx
2| B_xxxx | A_xxxx  | C_xxxx
3| C_xxxx | B_xxxx  | A_xxxx
```

.....
(each xxxx is different number)

I would like to sort each row to make table as below:

```
     A         B         C
1| A_xxxx | B_xxxx  | C_xxxx
2| A_xxxx | B_xxxx  | C_xxxx
3| A_xxxx | B_xxxx  | C_xxxx
```

....

How can I do this request?

Comment: Is there only ever a single character before the underscore and are they all in the range A-Z?

Comment: It is not a single character, but I can substitute it into single character before the underscore.
I just have a-d, so they are all in the range of A-Z.

Comment: Will all the values in column A start with the same characters before the underscore or does each row just need to be sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

This sub will do it with VBA:

```
Sub SortValsToCols()

Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim w2 As Worksheet
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim rowCounters As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim i As Long

Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to name of the worksheet containing data.
Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Change to name of a blank worksheet. The sorted data will end up here.
Set rRng = w1.Range("A1:C3") 'Change to range of cells containing data.

'Turn off ScreenUpdating to speed up execution.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Fills a dictionary with keys from A-Z and gives each an initial value of 1.
For i = 65 To 90
    rowCounters.Add Key:=Chr(i), Item:=1
Next i

'Loops thru all cells in range specified and adds the value after the last populated _
    cell in the relevant column to the target sheet.
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    w2.Range(Left$(rCell.Value, 1) & rowCounters(Left$(rCell.Value, 1))).FormulaR1C1 = rCell.Value
    rowCounters(Left$(rCell.Value, 1)) = rowCounters(Left$(rCell.Value, 1)) + 1
Next rCell

'Turn ScreenUpdating back on.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You'll need to change the 3 `SET` statements to suit your workbook and add “Microsoft Scripting Runtime” via Tools->References in the VBE before running.

Also assumes that all cell values start with `?_` where `?` is a single uppercase letter from A-Z .